# AndroidView() not calling the update block

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-view

I have the following setup:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PieChart(
    updateChart: (chart: PieChart) -> Unit,
    updateEvent: State<List<Transaction>>,
) {
  val update = updateEvent.value
  println("composable level")

    AndroidView(
        factory = { 
             // code that runs once
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(5.dp),
    ) {
        println("the update block")
        updateChart(it)
    }
```

Note that the `update` variable was merely added during debugging of this issue.

###### Expected behavior:

For every "composable level" there should be a "the update block".
According the docs:

> The update block can run multiple times (on the UI thread as well) due to recomposition, and it is the right place to set the new properties.

###### Actual behavior:

The output looks like:

```kotlin
"composable level"
"the update block"
"composable level"
"composable level"
... // everytime it recomposes
```

This seems like a strange issue. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

After checking where the regression starts, I found that this bug is not present in the main branch. Hence I feel like I have to include the factory body:

```
 AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            LineChart(context).apply {
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                )
```

This was taken and modified from the example given in the docs. Could this be related to the `context` here?

I have been trying to migrate this app from `compose-navigation` to `destinations-compose`.

### Edit 2:

After further investigation, both `context` refer to `MainActivity`. No change between the two.

### Edit 3:

So this was also in the docs, I don't know how I missed this:

> The AndroidView recomposes whenever a State read within the callback changes.

The fix was to read the state *inside* the `AndroidView` like so:

```
 AndroidView(
        factory = {
           // init code
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(5.dp),
    ) {
        val update = updateEvent.value // reading the state.
        updateChart(it)
    }
```

I will look further to clean up this mess and find a better way to solve this.

Now my question is: Why is this only happening here? why was it working previously ?
This is not a timing issue, I have to mention.

### Edit 4:

It seems like this originates from the Screen level composable where the lambda `updateChart` originates.
This parent composable seems to recompose and generate a new lambda, which causes the child to recompose, and thus the `AndroidView` to recompose as well.
Now trying to figure out what was causing the recomposition in one branch but not the other although the code seems nearly identical.

### Final edit:

I fixed it by adding a dummy state that just forces the UI to refresh. This is all due to me handling all the business in the viewModel and only exposing call-backs ... I will clean it up now, but otherwise it is fixed.